# How to implement the C# server side when using ASIFormDataRequest?

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, object

I am trying to use ASIFormDataRequest to send data to ASP.net server side.
I have created an aspx page.Currently I can get the two plain text. Howerver I don't know how to prase the NSdata in C# by Request.Form.

Here is Obj-C code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"code"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

This is Current C# code:

```
 string name = Request.Form["name"] == null ? "" : Request.Form["name"];
 string code = Request.Form["code"]==null?"":Request.Form["code"];
```

As you see ,in iphone, I try to send an image to C# server side, but I don't know how do it?

Comment: Yes,I know this. My question is how to implement C# code, just this question related to iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an image down to a WCF REST service, using ASIFormDataRequest.. here is an example from a project we have in production...

assumes I have a UIImage in a var called 'image'

```
NSString *surl = @"http:www.SomeRestService.com"    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];

ASIFormDataRequest *r = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[r setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[r setTimeOutSeconds:30];
[r setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; //default is POST (insert), 
[r setDelegate:self];
[r setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFail:)];
//[r addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"]   this will cause the call to fail.  No content-type header for this call.


NSMutableData *imageData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .35)]; //we are really compressing our images.. you can do what you want, of course.
[r setPostBody:imageData];
[r setDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageSaveDidFinish:)];
[r startAsynchronous];
```

OK, on the WCF side, you need to define a method that receives a System.IO.Stream, and that Stream needs to be the last parameter defined, it sould be a POST, and should not contain any other parameters as part of the POST body (you can define parameters in the URL and query string, although some purists would say that that's bad form for a REST POST).

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Upload", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
        public GenericObject SaveReceiptImage(System.IO.Stream imageStream)
        {
                            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = imageStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    ms.Position = 0;

                    if (ms.Length > 0)
                    {
                      //save your byte array to where you want
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      // woops, no image was passed in
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //bad error occured, log it
            }

            return whatever;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason，could you also show your WCF code in this thread? I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Hello Jason, you said that no other parameters in the POST body, so in iphone side, I only can send an image without any other parameters? Does it mean that I need to create a new method to get other parameters?

Comment: OK, see my updated post, it includes the server side code. Yes, you can add parameters, but they should be in the URL string, and then in the function itself, they need to appear before the System.IO.Stream

Answer (score 0):

please check the following links:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/29519-help-http-post-using-asiformdatarequest.html

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.  I think my iphone side code works well.The thing is how to write the C# server side.